# Number branches in a tree structure with MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi

My task is to transform a tree structure to a matrix structure in order to present it in a report.

I'm using Delphi 11.3, TADOQuery and MySQL version 8.

The tree structure that I want to transform to a matrix look like this showing the node Id and it's data.

[image]

coming from table treestructure where Nodes and Parents are identified with an Id,

Table treestructure

| Idx | Node | Parent | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | NULL | AA |
| 2 | 20 | 10 | BB |
| 3 | 30 | 20 | CC |
| 4 | 40 | 30 | DD |
| 5 | 50 | 20 | EE |
| 6 | 60 | 50 | FF |
| 7 | 70 | 20 | GG |

Where the Row in my coming matrix is the number of the branch in the tree as showed by numbers within () below:

[image]

To get the data to the matrix I use a RECURSIVE call like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS
(
 SELECT CAST(Node AS CHAR(255)) AS Path, 1 AS Branch, 1 AS Level, Node, Data
        FROM treestructure t WHERE Id = 10
 UNION ALL
 SELECT CONCAT(Path,".",t2.Node) AS Path,
        Branch // How to count up the Branch????, 
        Level + 1,
        t2.Node, 
        t2.Data 
   FROM treestructure t2 
 INNER JOIN tree ON t2.Parent = tree.Node
)
SELECT * FROM tree
ORDER BY Path
```

which returns the following result that I can transform to my matrix by using Branch and Level in combination.

| Path | Branch | Level | Node | Parent | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 1 | 10 | NULL | AA |
| 10,20 | 1 | 2 | 20 | 10 | BB |
| 10,20,30 | 1 | 3 | 30 | 20 | CC |
| 10,20,30,40 | 1 | 4 | 40 | 30 | DD |
| 10,20,50 | 2 | 3 | 50 | 20 | EE |
| 10,20,50,60 | 2 | 4 | 60 | 50 | FF |
| 10,20,70 | 3 | 2 | 70 | 20 | GG |

But my problem is that I can't find out how to calculatet or count up Branch within the recursive function.

One factor to use could be when path is shorter than the previous path then count upp branch with one. But how to do that in a query?

The final result will look like below after transforming the result above.

| Branch | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | BB | CC | DD |
| 2 |  |  | EE | FF |
| 3 |  | GG |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*...my problem is that I can't find out how to calculate or count up Branch...*

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS
(
 SELECT CAST(Node AS CHAR(255)) AS Path, 1 AS Branch, 1 AS Level, Node, Data
        FROM treestructure t WHERE Node = 10
 UNION ALL
 SELECT CONCAT(Path,",",t2.Node) AS Path,
        0 Branch , 
        Level + 1,
        t2.Node, 
        t2.Data 
   FROM treestructure t2 
 INNER JOIN tree ON t2.Parent = tree.Node
)
select replace(path,',','.') path, level, node, data, 
       sum(ifnull(mrk, 1)) over (order by path) branch
from (
  select path, level, node, data, 
         1-sign(find_in_set(lag(node) over (order by path), path)) mrk
  FROM tree ) t
ORDER BY Path
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mi8rPFmb)

- Use comma instead of dot in recursive query (or make another column in recursion, separated with commas),
- we need this comma to use `find_in_set`. Whenever previous node (`lag`) is absent in current row path it means it is new branch, this row is marked as 1 `mrk`
- use analytic sum to count marked rows. This sum is your `branch` value.
- now you have everything to make pivot based on values `level` and `branch`,
- replace commas in path with dots if needed.

Comment: Worked perfektly, thanks' a lot.